# jax-ws regarding endpointinterface

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

have defined a Java Interface with the annotation **@WebService**
Compiled the code which went fine

Example:

```
@WebService
public interface HelloWorldIfc{
```

Now I tried to define an endpointinterface as

```
 @WebService (endpointInterface = "com.ws.HelloWorldIfc")
    public interface HelloWorldIfc{
```

This compiled fine too

So - should I be defining the endpoint interface on the interface or on implementing class ?
is this attribute of any use - what is its purpose ?
what happens if I dont define it - what do I lose ?
Thanks,
satish

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[The JAX-WS Specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr224/index.html) makes this cleas in section 3.3, page 30:

You can use the `endpointInterface` attribute to separate between the implementing class and the interface. Basically, this determines what will be mapped to your `wsdl:portType` when you deploy the service and the `wsdl:definition` is generated.

If you *do not* define the `endpointInterface` all public methods of the annotated class will be mapped to `wsdl:operation` (as long as you do not influence this behaviour with `@WebMethod` annotations).

If you *do* define the `endpointInterface`, it has to point to some type which the annotated class implements (or, well, itself as demonstrated in your question). Then, the public methods of this type are used for mapping the `wsdl:portType`, instead of the methods of the annotated class.

To sum up: The definition of `endpointInterface` only makes sense if you use the `@WebService` on an implementing class and want your WSDL to be generated based on the interface it implements. In your current setting where you use the annotation on the interface `com.ws.HelloWorldIfc`, there really isn't any difference. So you lose nothing by just skipping it. The annotation is useful if you want your implementation class to provide public methods that should not go into the generated WSDL.

Comment: thank you very much - your explanation made a lot of sense  I copied your comments into a text editor and removed / trimmed down and focussed on the points mentioned - it now makes sense particularly - "The annotation is useful if you want your implementation class to provide public methods that should not go into the generated WSDL"  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To define the endpointInterface is usefull because @WebParam annotations of the interface methodes are working without defining them again in the implementation class.