# How to avoid CXF codegen from changing element names in schema?

Tags: cxf

I am using cxf-codegen-plugin v. 3.2.4 in a maven project. WSDL refers to the schema:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://mynamespace/"
                        schemaLocation="../schema/MySchema.xsd"/>
```

But when the generated Server runs, the published wsdl refers to the schema like this:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://mynamespace/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:9999/?xsd=1"/>
```

And this generated xsd changed the argument names for a given method. The original schema has the following definition:

```
<xs:complexType name="myMethod">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="messageHeader" type="tns:soapMessageHeader" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="myId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="mySecondId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="myThirdId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Whereas the generated schema has the following:

```
<xs:complexType name="myMethod">
<xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="arg0" type="tns:soapMessageHeader" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="arg1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="arg2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="arg3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="arg4" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

It changed the element names from the defined ones to "arg0", "arg...". I need this not to be done.

My pom has this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${source.wsdl.path}</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/MyServiceDefinition.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The automatically generated interface for the service has the @WebParam annotation.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In http://www.benmccann.com/web-services-tutorial-with-apache-cxf the author indicates the usage of **endpointInterface** annotation attribute in order to respect the annotations inside the automatically generated interface (by cxf itself):

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.company.auth.service.AuthService",
            serviceName = "corporateAuthService")
```

This alternative requires no additional xml configuration.

Tomcat EE documentation gives us a completed example: http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-webservice

Yet another stackoverflow question that could be related: [jax-ws regarding endpointinterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320609/jax-ws-regarding-endpointinterface)

Answer (score 0):

I have just figured it out: although the generated interface for the service has the @WebParam annotation, the respective concrete class that implements the EndPoint does not have it. I thought that wouldn't be a problem, since the interface has the annotation. Then I tried to add them to the parameters and voilá! The generated xsd suddenly comes out right and I can read the parameters!